# Select items from a NodeList and change value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to change values automatically from a nodeList, I have these options in a select and I'm trying to change the value of the "price" span but is not working, it appears empty:

How can I access each element of moviePrice and change the value?

```js
const moviePrice = document.querySelectorAll('.price');

function convertCurrency() {
  const currency_one = currency.value;
  const amountMovie = movieSelect.value;
  fetch(`https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/latest/USD`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      const rate = data.conversion_rates[currency_one];
      const ratedPrice = (amountMovie * rate).toFixed(2);

      currencyTotal.innerText = currency_one;

      moviePrice.forEach(element => {
        element.innerText = ratedPrice + ' ' + currency_one;

        console.log(element); //This is not showing in the console
      });

      ticketPrice = ratedPrice;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error en la conversión de moneda:', error);
    })
}
```

```html
<select id="movie" autocomplete="off">
  <option value="10">Avengers: Endgame <span class="price"></span></option>
  <option value="12">Joker <span class="price"></span></option>
  <option value="8">Toy Story 4 <span class="price"></span></option>
  <option value="9">The Lion King <span class="price"></span></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your HTML is not valid - a `span` is **not** a legitimate child of an `option` element

Comment: You can assign `dataset` attributes and values to each `option` within the `select` menu - these can later be retrieved using Javascript if subsequent processing of the document occur. So your ajax callback would set the updated price as `el.dataset.price=x` etc where `el` is a reference to the `option` element

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version that is not usong the illegal span in the option.

Uncomment the fetch and delete the `let conversion_rates = data.conversion_rates;` when happy

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const currency = document.getElementById('currency');
  const currencyTotal = document.getElementById('currencyTotal');
  const movieSelect = document.getElementById('movie');
  const options = movieSelect.querySelectorAll('option');
  /*  let conversion_rates;
    fetch(`https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/latest/USD`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => conversion_rates = data.conversion_rates)
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error en la conversión de moneda:', error);
      });
  */

  let data = {
    "result": "success",
    "documentation": "https://www.exchange rate-api.com/docs",
    "terms_of_use": "https://www.exchange rate-api.com/terms",
    "time_last_update_unix": 1613742300,
    "time_last_update_utc": "Fri, 19 Feb 2021 13:45:00 +0000",
    "time_next_update_unix": 1613742600,
    "time_next_update_utc": "Fri, 19 Feb 2021 13:50:00 +0000",
    "base_code": "USD",
    "conversion_rates": {
      "USD": 1,
      "AED": 3.6725,
      "AFN": 77.0123,
      "ALL": 102.1183,
      "AMD": 524.1769,
      "ANG": 1.79,
      "AOA": 648.8211,
      "ARS": 88.8728,
      "AUD": 1.2809,
      "AWG": 1.79,
      "AZN": 1.6939,
      "BAM": 1.6135,
      "BOB": 6.8774,
    }
  };
  let conversion_rates = data.conversion_rates;
  const changePrices = () => {
    const currency_one = currency.value;
    const rate = conversion_rates[currency_one];
    currencyTotal.innerText = currency_one;

    options.forEach((opt, i) => {
      if (i > 0) {
        const [amountMovie, title] = opt.value.split(" - ");
        console.log(amountMovie, title)
        const ratedPrice = (amountMovie * rate).toFixed(2);
        opt.textContent = `${title} - ${ratedPrice}`;
      }
    })
  };

  movieSelect.addEventListener('change', changePrices);
  currency.addEventListener('change', changePrices)
  changePrices()
});
```

```html
<select id="currency">
  <option value="USD">Currency</option>
  <option value="AUD">AUD</option>
  <option value="ANG">ANG</option>
</select>
<select id="movie">
  <option value="">Movie</option>
  <option value="10 - Avengers: Endgame"></option>
  <option value="12 - Joker"></option>
  <option value="8 - Toy Story 4"></option>
  <option value="9 - The Lion King"></option>
</select>
<span id="currencyTotal"></span>
```